# Horrendously slow admin and pretty slow sites

Tags: performance

We host dozens of plain PHP sites that respond within milliseconds. The average page load time is around 10 ms. One of our users installed 2x WP 5.5 sites and gradually upgraded them to 6.0. Their page load times are 5 seconds and up, and it is slowing down their admin users.

The sites run on a FreeBSD 13.1 VM, on a WS 2012 host. The hardware is 2x 2nd gen Xeon 3 GHz, 16 physical cores total, off an SSD. There is plenty of free RAM, both on the VM and on the host.

We suggested they install XML-RPC plugin and disable heartbeat and other resource-hungry items. It did not help at all. We looked at all of the top solutions on Google to "wordpress admin slow" but none helped make any difference whatsoever.

We tried to temporarily put their sites on the Apache that runs directly on the host OS, but it made matters ever so slightly worse (by a factor of 10%) across both the admin and the actual sites.

When an admin page (dashboard, plugins, media, posts - does not matter which) is requested, Wordpress seems to be taking its time w/o any signs of resource utilization. It simply sits for 5+ seconds, w/o CPU load or disk activity, and then the CPU load spikes and there is a disk access, for a split second, and the page loads. It happens equally with a vanilla Wordpress as well as with their full sets of plugins that include WooCommerce and a tiny handful of others. Any theme.

Please help understand why Wordpress is taking so much time, to load trivial pages.

Comment: Have you tried running a lighthouse scan on the site to see what performance issues google identifies? Just a thought.

Comment: Try to install this on the website and see everything that happens. You will most probably get some info about slow queries and other stuff: https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/ I personally use this a lot on WP

Comment: Try to disable all the plugins one by one and see when it gets better. If it doesn't, switch to a default theme and check again. Install a fresh WP on the server and see how that behaves.

Comment: I'll second Query Monitor. If you have a staging or local development site which also exhibits the behavior and want to really dig in, you can also set up an Xdebug/Webgrind environment. But often times Query Monitor is sufficient.